# How to allow my Asp.net MVC 3 web app using MathJax to accept user input $x<y>z$?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, xss, csrf, mathjax

I am developing a mathematics site using Asp.Net MVC 3 + Razor + MathJax.
MathJax is a javascript library to render TeX or LaTeX codes on the web browser.
And TeX or LaTeX codes represent mathematics contents such as an inline math `$y=mx+c$` and a displayed math `\[y=mx+c\]`.

Right now my site can accept input, for example, `$x<y$`. However it cannot accept `$x<y>z$` because the framework regards this input is vulnerable to XSS and XSRF.

Shortly speaking, what I should do to accomplish what I want but it does not open security vulnerability.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you using the ValidateInputAttribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 you could decorate the property of you model that needs to accept this input with the [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute. This way you are not forced to disable input validation for the entire controller action which was previously done by decorating it with the [`[ValidateInput]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute. So on your model

```
public class MathematicsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string MathematicFormula { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(MathematicsViewModel model)
{
    // model.MathematicFormula will now accept input like  $x<y>z$
    ...
}
```

And inside your view you could have a textbox named `MathematicFormula` in which the user could type those characters and you won't get exception.

Also don't forget to set the following in your web.config or this attribute won't have effect in .NET 4.0 (which is what ASP.NET MVC 3 uses):

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Comment: I don't set this `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` but it still works. By the way, using `AllowHtml` does not open security vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Recycle Bin, this attribute allows you to store HTML inside your model property. This means that you will have to be careful when you are showing this value back to a view. You need to ensure that it is properly HTML encoded. Luckily Razor `@` encodes by default so you are safe if you use `@Model.MathematicFormula` inside a view.

Comment: For the sake of completness I inform this. According to Steven Anderson's book titled Pro Asp.Net MVC 2 Framework on page 571, the `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` is needed only in .NET 4 when you set `[ValidateInput(false)]`. So it is not needed when setting `[AllowHtml]` as I did successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [ValidateInputAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) on your action method

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ViewResult Create() {

}
```

### Edit

And if you use .net 4, don't forget to add `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` to the `web.config` as follows

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No. I don't use that attribute.